# After executing mongodb-> db.collection.updateone(), the updated document is not persisting the change

Tags: mongodb

mongodb updateone() is showing that the file is updated correctly, but when queried afterward it shows the changed value but after a min it reverts to original one still has the same values.

trying to update a collection using command  **db.collection.update({name:"Job1"},{$set:{status:"STOP"}})**
*{
"entityId" : NumberLong(1158),
"name" : "Job1",
"status" : "START"
}*

After execution getting below result
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

And when I query, for some time it shows the change value and afterward revert to the original value (Which was before executing the update command)

Comment: As it is updating, that means your query is fine. Time to look into some other places in ptoject to find out if anywhere else this condition is getting reversed or not